# dirname() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: dirname

I use a mail form `formtoemailpro.php` and have done for years and on multiple sites without problem. One client uses a private server and the owner has configured the server not to run the script because it contains `dirname`.
     `dirname()` has been disabled for security reasons

I have not come across this before and all te major hosting companies run this script without problem, Is this something I should be concerned about.

Comment: Should I post the php here?

Comment: yes, I want to see ur code